# Zone.js catches unhandled rejection in promises from outside my Angular Elements component

Tags: angular, custom-element, zone

I created [angular custom element](https://angular.io/guide/elements)  and tried to use it on really complicated page (which I don't control, so there are another scripts running). In result zone.js starts catches and wrapping all unhandled rejections from outside of my component. And with one of this errors zone stops working completely.

I tried `__zone_symbol__DISABLE_WRAPPING_UNCAUGHT_PROMISE_REJECTION = true` but it didn't work, in fact I don't understand what it did at all, since nothing changed. I used it as [in this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rjubiv?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Just a hutch, but perhaps you can use `this.zone.run` or `this.zone.runOutsideAngular`...